# Is my Spring Boot controller secure when ithe may include id?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have started implement spring security for my rest controller.
Background
The security design is JWT token with spring security.

I have work on implemeting WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
 httpSecurity
         .sessionManagement()
             .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
             .and()
         .authorizeRequests()            
             .antMatchers("/managers/**").hasRole("MANAGER_USER)
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and().cors();
httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

My question is relating to **basic understanding**:
When calling the rest controller endpoint from Angular I have rest call which include manager id,
when a call is made the server return list of users for the manager.

The security working fine, only user with the MANAGER_USER role is able to access the method, otherwise return 403.
Teoriaclly, Angular can send a request with different manager id and retrive users which it not belong to him.
In postman you can easily change the id and retreive different results but is there a risk that
someone hack the Angular app to send different id? And if yes, no solution can be found for this?

For example, some urls include ids in the url, so the user can actually chnage the id in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you explained it, anyone can send a http request via postman, browser etc. So yes, frontend frameworks can also be modified to send out custom requests - but that's not really the question here I believe. Everything on the frontend side is unsafe and should be considered so, the layers of security we add to the frontend side are basically to keep regular users from not doing something we don't want. A tech-savvy person will find the endpoints and figure out how your system works regardless of how good of frontend security you put up. Never trust the frontend.

If you want to avoid an authenticated person with role `MANAGER_USER` to only query "users" that only belong to them you need to increase security or re-configure how the users are queried.

For the latter, it could be the way your database is set-up. Associate `manager_id` with each `user` and have endpoint `/GET/users` return only users that belong to the manager making the query. (idk what your endpoint or id's actually are, I just used the above ones as an example).

Comment: You mentioned /GET/users return only users that belong to the manager making the query. But anyone can provide different id isn't? and by doing that get different users. My ids which are exposed in the urls are random created to avoid someone to increment the last number for example. The question if this is enough?!

Comment: No, it is not enough if you rely on query params. Get `manager_id` from session which was populated in the backend during the authentication process. So now whenever someone asks `/GET/users` backend will check that the user is authenticated, and who it is. No need to supply `manager_id` via queryParams.

Comment: well, my question is general, you basically saying that no url should include id which is very basic in an application to have. The angular want for example to retreive specific entity per id.

Comment: In general we use queryParams to query different data, that is true - quite common indeed. I am saying that if you want to control who gets to query what you need to implement a mechanism to verify the user. You've done that with `hasRole()` but that's partial solution. Like you said now every person with role `MANAGER_USER` can query all users if they just change the id. Second step to this problem could be to implement a mechanism which checks, that manager with specific `id` can only query users they should have access to.

Comment: Ok, got you now! you saying that while allowing the rest api call, I'll need to return result based on the authincated user, I will have a look on this closer now.

Comment: In case it helps, the issue here is what's known as [insecure direct object reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insecure_direct_object_reference). We discussed this in our SpringOne 2021 talk (starting [here](https://youtu.be/5tlU_Vjv8Ns?t=1689)) and some ways to mitigate it. You may want to review the whole presentation for context.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg the link to video was helping me a lot, thank to that I was able implement "declerative security"! in my controllers, however some required specific method so I ended up with SecurityService for each microservice, a security method has to go the database and check things (not all data availavle in the principal or UserDetails).

Comment: @user2304483 great! I think that's a great starting point.